# Xubuntu Mouse sensitivity way too high

Tags: mouse, settings, xubuntu

I am pretty new to Linux, this is my first real time using Xubuntu (used Ubuntu before, and raspbian on my RPI), and I have a mouse that is way too sensitive. If I move my mouse 1cm it's on the other side of the screen, that sensitive.

I have turned all mouse sliders as far down as I can, and I don't even notice anything becoming less sensitive. For some reason the mouse settings menu also displays that I have two Razer Deathadder 2013's plugged in, even though I only have one. Sliders are down on both, tried some things with `xset m 5 1` but it only gets worse.

How do I get a human level of mouse sensitivity?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=864864&page=2 saying to replug the usb mouse... it worked for me. the same solution here:http://askubuntu.com/a/360045/47206

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track with `xset m`, but you will probably want a far lower setting than what you are using ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#Using_xset)):

> First get the current setting:
>
> ```
> xset q | grep -A 1 Pointer
> ```
>
> To set new values, type:
>
> ```
> xset m ACCELERATION THRESHOLD
> ```
>
> where ACCELERATION defines how many times faster the cursor will move
>   than the default speed, when the cursor moves more than THRESHOLD
>   pixels in a short time. ACCELERATION can be a fraction, so if you want
>   to slow down the mouse you can use 1/2, and if 3 is slightly too fast,
>   but 2 is too slow, you can use 5/2, etc.

So, what you are doing with `xset m 5 1` is setting the mouse to be 5 times **faster** than the default setting. Try something like `xset m 1/3 4`.

Comment: Tried it, but somehow doesn't work. Every setting I changed for xset m (tried things like 1, 1/2, 9/10 and even 1/100) but it just stays the same.

Comment: @IPDGino strange, did you also try playing with the threshold values?

Comment: Yes. From tried a few ranging from 1 to 1000. Is it not working because Linux says I have 2 Razer Deathadder 2013's plugged in?

Comment: This solution worked for me but upon restart it was reset back to the old values. Any way to save the configuration?

Comment: @levitopher just add the `xset` command to your `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this was driving me insane and I just figured how to fix it. Since none of the solutions I found online had worked for me, I might as well post mine here.

You actually can decrease the insane sensitivity a bit by setting `libinput Accel Speed` as close to the allowed minimum of `-1` as possible.

```
xinput --set-prop      8 "libinput Accel Speed" -0.9999
```

(change the number 8 by your pointer ID)

This however will only take you so far with most Mamba mice. What really does the trick is to SCALE the input down by some constant. In my mouse this property is called "Coordinate Transformation Matrix", which I guess will have a similar if not identical name for other mice.

```
$ xinput --list-props 8
Device 'Razer Razer Mamba Tournament Edition':
Device Enabled (155):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
...
```

So scaling down the first two 1.0000 (corresponding to X- and Y- axis change) to 0.5000 or something else actually makes the mouse usable. In my case, this is accomplished with:

```
xinput --set-prop      8  157 0.500000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

Hope this helps somebody else in my situation.

Comment: Using Xubuntu 22.04.3 which is XFCE version 4.16, with a "X-keys L-Trac Trackball": I noticed that `xset m <acceleration> <threshhold>` command was **completely** ignored (the actual acceleration as observed using the trackball did **not** change). But using Xubuntu's Settings Manager, using "Mouse and Touchpad", and moving the slider around, then worked. Then, using `xinput --list-props "Clearly Superior Technologies. CST Laser Trackball"` showed that "libinput Accel Speed" **did** change. ...

Comment: ... Thus, for some reason I do not yet understand, the use of `xset m` appears to be ineffective. Also, I found that the `xinput` range for "libinput Accel Speed" is [-1,1] versus [0,10] in the "Mouse and Touchpad" GUI (see "Pointer acceleration is normalized" at https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/configuration.html#:~:text=Pointer%20acceleration%20is%20normalized) ...

Comment: ... So to remove the acceleration as far down as I could go, without using that matrix stuff which appears to be a trade-secret w.r.t. documentation, I use this: `xinput --set-prop "Clearly Superior Technologies. CST Laser Trackball" "libinput Accel Speed" -1`

Comment: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/absolute-axes.html#calibration-of-absolute-devices is the closest I could find for "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" but it does not show what the numbers mean w.r.t. the values sent to `xinput --set-prop ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed MATE control center, and it worked for me.

In MATE control center, move the slides, then set them to the slowest acceleration and slowest sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this works for me:

```
xinput --set-prop "NAME_OF_YOUR_MOUSE" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 3
```

Where *NAME_OF_YOUR_MOUSE* is the name of your mouse, which can be obtained by simply typing

```
xinput
```

in a terminal.

You can add this command to "Application Autostart", in "Session and Startup" settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest solution was:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to add some explanation on _why_ this would solve the OPs problem (and thereby what you think caused the OPs problem in the first place).